# Changing label title used for UIMenuController right before it appears

Tags: ios, swift, uimenucontroller

Is it possible to change the title of a `UIMenuItem` used by `UIMenuController` when it's about to popup?

For example, when I allow the `copy` menu in `override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool`, instead of displaying the label "Copy", it would display the label copy and the text I want to copy like: "Copy TEXT_I_M_ABOUT_TO_COPY"?

I thought about making a custom UIMenuItem but when I create it, it's when I have to give the text for the title. Is it possible to change that text right before it appears?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it, I don't know if it's the best one but seems to work so far.

You have to create a UIMenuItem, add it to your UIMenuController shared instance:

```
let frame = frameWhereYouWantToMakeTheMenuAppear.frame

let rect = CGRectMake(frame.midX, frame.maxY, 1, 1)

let customPasteMenu = UIMenuItem(title: "Paste", action: "customPaste:")

let menuController = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
menuController.menuItems = [customPasteMenu]
menuController.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDirection.Up

menuController.setTargetRect(rect, inView: displayView)
menuController.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
```

Then in the method `func canPerformAction`, you do your tests whether or not you allow the action, and once you're about to return `true`, that's where you get the `UIMenuController` shared instance, get your menu item from the list of menu items and change the title.

```
override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action == "customPaste:" {
        // do your tests and get what you want to paste for example
        let menuController = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
        if let customPasteMenu = menuController.menuItems?.first {
            customPasteMenu.title = yourTitle + FormatterHelper.formatAmount(stringToPaste)
        }

        return true
    }
    return false
}
```